# How to pass props and stop event propagation in React using ES2015?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple component set up and am trying to figure out how to pass a param AND stop event propagation in the same handler. In the linked example, I'd like to pass the number associated with the square along to the click handler, prevent the default click behavior and use the number to increment the counter. Every technique I try to pass along additional params stops the `e.preventDefault()` from preventing the default behavior.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKGKBz?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the value and the event to the handleClick function.

Something like this

```
handleClick(number,e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({total: this.state.total + number})
  }

 render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>{this.state.total}</h1>
       {[0,1,2,3,4].map( (number) => {
       return (
         <a href="/" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(number,e)}>{number}</a>
        )
     })}
         </div>
     )
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/565/)

or

```
handleClick(number,e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({total: this.state.total + number})
}

render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>{this.state.total}</h1>
       {[0,1,2,3,4].map( (number) => {
       return (
         <a href="/" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,number)}>{number}</a>
        )
     })}
         </div>
     )
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/568/)

Comment: so, this works - what I was missing was passing the event into the handler. Why do I need to include the 'e' in (e) => {} as opposed to just specifying it in the params? I think that's my understanding breakdown. Thanks!

Comment: because the SyntheticEvent is passed to the event handler function, in this case was (e) => {} . I added a second way to pass params without using a function inside your onClick event.